# To better understand 'PixelValues' of regionprops

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I was reading the documentation of `regionprops` and found out that if the image being labeled is grayscale, `regionprops` will find the `PixelValues` as well which is defined as:

> 'PixelValues' — p-by-1 vector, where p is the number of pixels in the
>   region. Each element in the vector contains the value of a pixel in
>   the region.

Is the pixel value the grayscale value of the pixel? Like between 0 and 255? also is it safe to assume that the region mentioned here being the labeled connected component obtained using `bwlabel`.

So I wanted to see the pixel value of each pixel (I knew it would be a mesh and not clear but with the help of zoom I would be able to read the values) But the code I used produced a weird result. As in the results are in it did not show clear boxes around each area showing the pixel value (like it did with `stats.Area`). This is what I got:

[image]

Why are the text boxes so long?  and why does it contain decimals? When I type `stats(1).PixelValues` I get a [2159x1] vector like so

```
ans =

  125
  128
  130
  126
  137
  101
  131
   28
```

Here is my code

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('W1\Writer1_01_02.jpg'));
bw_normal = im2bw(img, graythresh(img));
bw = imcomplement(bw_normal);
[label,n] = bwlabel(bw);
stats = regionprops(label, img, {'Area', 'Centroid', 'BoundingBox', 'PixelValues'});

imshow(img);

%To display text box on CC

for j = 1:numel(stats)
         text(stats(j).Centroid(1),stats(j).Centroid(2), ...
        sprintf('%2.1f', stats(j).PixelValues), ...
        'EdgeColor','b','Color','r');
     end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask several questions here. I'll try and answer.

1. When asking for `'PixelValues'` you get a vector with the gray-scale values of the pixels in input `img` corresponding to the labeled region in `label`. That is,  `stats(ii).PixelValues` is a **vector** with number of elements equal to the number of pixels in the `ii`-th region. The values of this vector is the gray-scale values taken from the corresponding pixels in `img`.
2. The range of values in `'PixelValues'` depends on the input `img`. If the values of `img` are between 0..255 so will the values be. If you converted `img` to double (e.g., using `im2double`) the values will rang ein 0..1
3. Your text boxes are long because they show you ALL pixel values of each region (values of MANY pixels). They contain decimal because this is the way you printed them with `'%2.1f'`. Use `'%d'` to print integer values. You might also want to add a space there.
4. If all you want is to inspect the pixel values, you migt want to try tool like `impixelinfo`.